# Search without special characters

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Suppose I have values like `CA-123` and `C-A123` and `CA1-23` and so on indexed in my ElasticSearch. Is there a way to find these values by searching with the value `CA123` by using java API?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Regex queries:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Something like this ought to work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "field_name": "C(-A|A-)123"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think that what I need is a bit more complicated. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check wildcard queries :

Here' [Wildcard Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html).